# EF Power Tools not working in VS 2013

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I installed the Entity Framework Power Tools from the Extensions and Updates menu in VS 2013 PRO.
I restarted my computer and opened my Solution with C# projects.
Now there should be a menu entry with Entity Framework when right clicking one of my C# projects but there isn't.

I opened again the Extensions and Updates form and it shows me the the Power Tools have been installed.

Here is the installation Log:

```
12.05.2015 13:26:37 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
12.05.2015 13:26:37 - -------------------------------------------
12.05.2015 13:26:37 - Initializing Install...
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - Extension Details...
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   Identifier      : 2b119c79-9836-46e2-b5ed-eb766cebbf7c
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   Name            : Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   Author          : Microsoft
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   Version         : 0.9.0.0
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   Description     : Preview of useful design-time features for DbContext.

When right-clicking on a C# project, the following context menu function is supported:
1) Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database. 

When right-clicking on a file containing a derived DbContext class, the following context menu functions are supported:

1) View Entity Data Model XML - Displays the EDMX XML representing the underlying Code First model.
2) View Entity Data Model DDL SQL - Displays the DDL SQL corresponding to the SSDL in the underlying EDM Model.
3) Generate Views - Generates pre-compiled views used by the EF runtime to improve start-up performance. Adds the generated views file to the containing project.
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   Locale          : en-US
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   MoreInfoURL     : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=327691
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0]
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - 
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   Supported Products : 
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -           Version : [10.0]
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -           Version : [11.0]
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -           Version : [12.0]
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - 
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -   References      : 
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       -------------------------------------------------------
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       Version      : [10.0,)
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       MoreInfoURL  : 
12.05.2015 13:26:38 -       Nested       : No
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - 
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - 
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - Searching for applicable products...
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - An extension with a matching Identifier is already installed to this product.
12.05.2015 13:26:38 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
12.05.2015 13:26:42 - The extension with ID '2b119c79-9836-46e2-b5ed-eb766cebbf7c' is not installed to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013.
12.05.2015 13:26:42 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
12.05.2015 13:26:42 - Found installed product - Global Location
12.05.2015 13:26:42 - Found installed product - ssms
12.05.2015 13:26:44 - The following target products have been selected...
12.05.2015 13:26:44 -   Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
12.05.2015 13:26:44 - 
12.05.2015 13:26:44 - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013...
12.05.2015 13:26:44 - Install to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 completed successfully. The extension has been installed to C:\USERS\USER\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\12.0\EXTENSIONS\M2DVCZNM.VZR\
```

My Question is how to get Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 work on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution. 
Something was wrong with my Postsharp installation on Visual Studio. After installing an update the Entity Framework menu appeared.
So make sure that all your visual studio extensions work correct.